# Bayesian optimization with xgb.cv and xgb.XGBClassifier - Mismatch between AUC scores

Tags: python, hyperparameter, boosting, bayesian-optimization

I'm doing bayesian hyperparameter optimization with `bayes_opt` and maximizing the AUC.

I'm noticing a big discrepancy between the cross-validation scores that I obtain during optimization and the scores that I obtain when predicting and testing the model.

Here's my code. To simplify, I'll be optimizing `gamma` only and do only `n_iter = 10`

```
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
import xgboost as xgb

def optimize_xgb(train, params):
    def xgb_crossval(gamma = None):
    
        params['gamma'] = gamma
    
        cv_results = xgb.cv(
            params,
            train,
            num_boost_round=100, # default n_estimators in XGBClassifier is 100 
            stratified = True,
            seed=23,
            nfold=5,
            metrics='auc',
            early_stopping_rounds=100
          ) 
    
        return cv_results['test-auc-mean'].max()

    optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
        f=xgb_crossval,
        pbounds={
        "gamma": (0, 1),
        },
        random_state=12,
        verbose=10)

    optimizer.maximize(init_points = 3, n_iter=10, acq='ei', kappa = 3, alpha = 1e-3)

    print("Final result:", optimizer.max)
    return optimizer.max
```

Because `xgb.cv` and `xgb.XGBClassifier` have different default parameters for `eta/learning_rate` (0.3 vs 0.1) and for `max_depth` (6 vs 3), I initialize `params` with the defaults values of `xgb.XGBClassifier` (so that `xgb.cv` gets the same default values)

```
params = {
    'max_depth': 3, #default value in xgb.XGBClassifier
    'eta':.1, #default value in xgb.XGBClassifier
    'objective':'binary:logistic',
}

train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)
best = optimize_xgb(train, params)
```

And I obtain the following:

```
|   iter    |  target   |   gamma   |
-------------------------------------
|  1        |  0.8212   |  0.1542   |
|  2        |  0.8103   |  0.74     |
|  3        |  0.8344   |  0.2633   |
|  4        |  0.8344   |  0.2633   |
|  5        |  0.8321   |  0.28     |
|  6        |  0.8312   |  0.2355   |
|  7        |  0.8006   |  1.0      |
|  8        |  0.8203   |  0.4947   |
|  9        |  0.8359   |  0.0      |
|  10       |  0.8335   |  0.0401   |
|  11       |  0.8      |  0.6017   |
|  12       |  0.8159   |  0.4012   |
|  13       |  0.8394   |  0.01264  |
=====================================
Final result: {'target': 0.8394116, 'params': {'gamma': 0.012638204185692193}}
```

Notice how AUC's are all above 0.8.

However, when I try to test my model, AUC values are *always* lower than during optimization.

```
params['gamma'] = best['params']['gamma'] # learning rate is already 0.1 as default in xgb.XGBClassifier
xb_es = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)
xb_es = xb_es.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=5, eval_metric=["auc","logloss"], eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)], verbose = 1)
```

And I obtain (used `early_stopping_rounds=5` to simplify):

```
[0] validation_0-auc:0.926353   validation_0-logloss:0.647199   validation_1-auc:0.630303   validation_1-logloss:0.676592
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'validation_1-logloss' will be used for early stopping.

Will train until validation_1-logloss hasn't improved in 5 rounds.
[1] validation_0-auc:0.923706   validation_0-logloss:0.613415   validation_1-auc:0.719192       validation_1-logloss:0.651203
[2] validation_0-auc:0.928882   validation_0-logloss:0.584485   validation_1-auc:0.69899    validation_1-logloss:0.641244
[3] validation_0-auc:0.946353   validation_0-logloss:0.558989   validation_1-auc:0.731313   validation_1-logloss:0.62868
[4] validation_0-auc:0.953706   validation_0-logloss:0.53031    validation_1-auc:0.727273   validation_1-logloss:0.627571
[5] validation_0-auc:0.958647   validation_0-logloss:0.505348   validation_1-auc:0.715151   validation_1-logloss:0.628144
[6] validation_0-auc:0.960059   validation_0-logloss:0.487721   validation_1-auc:0.715151   validation_1-logloss:0.61783
[7] validation_0-auc:0.973882   validation_0-logloss:0.459568   validation_1-auc:0.682828   validation_1-logloss:0.629029
[8] validation_0-auc:0.978706   validation_0-logloss:0.438147   validation_1-auc:0.658586   validation_1-logloss:0.637697
[9] validation_0-auc:0.980471   validation_0-logloss:0.421054   validation_1-auc:0.640404   validation_1-logloss:0.645252
[10]    validation_0-auc:0.980941   validation_0-logloss:0.406797   validation_1-auc:0.626263   validation_1-logloss:0.653234
[11]    validation_0-auc:0.984824   validation_0-logloss:0.38987    validation_1-auc:0.642424   validation_1-logloss:0.647176
Stopping. Best iteration:
[6] validation_0-auc:0.960059   validation_0-logloss:0.487721   validation_1-auc:0.715151   validation_1-logloss:0.61783
```

When I then try to predict:

```
pred_probs_xb = xb_es.predict_proba(X_test,ntree_limit=xb_es.best_ntree_limit)
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_probs_xb[:,1]))
```

I obtain:

```
0.5164285714285715
```

I don't know where this discrepancy originates. I suspected it had to do with optimizing parameters using `xgb.cv` and then fitting the model using sklearn wrapper `xgb.XGBClassifier` but I've set the same parameters for both and there's still a big discrepancy. Also I suspected it had to do with my train-test-split, but no matter the split, the the `xgb.cv` scores are always (significantly) higher than the predicted scores.

I seem to missing something out while transfering the best parameters from the bayesian optimization onto model training, but I can't figure out exactly what. Is it related to different defaults? Objective function? `optimizer.maximize` parameters? Any help with be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135987/why-xgboost-cv-and-sklearn-cross-val-score-give-different-results).

`XGBOOst`'s CV does shuffling before partitioning the data. Because my samples are not independently and identically distributed ([3.1.3. A note on shuffling](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)) I got an inflated validation score